# Why to use a Deque instead of inbuilt Stack<>?

Tags: java, collections, stack, deprecated, obsolete

The [Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) says that a `Stack` should preferably be created from a `Deque`, rather than using the quintessential `Stack<>`.  Unfortunately, it does not emphasize *why so*.

> Deques can also be used as LIFO (Last-In-First-Out) stacks. This interface should be used in preference to the legacy Stack class. When a deque is used as a stack, elements are pushed and popped from the beginning of the deque.

Could someone please point out why so?  Similarly, are there other instances wherein we should avoid using the inbuilt `Collections` objects?  I am a C++ developer moving onto Java, hence any such subtle pointers would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Stack extends Vector. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated

Comment: @PatrickParker, well, I don't think that question answers my doubt.  Come on, the accepted answer just says _"As for a Stack equivalent - I'd look at Deque/ArrayDeque to start with."_  Do you think it is enough to classify it as a dup?

Comment: P.K. - If you read more attentively, you would notice that Stack is an extension of Vector. In other words, every thing they are saying about Vector _also_ applies to Stack.

Comment: @P.K. You should read all the answers on that question.

Comment: Read also this answer which discusses stacks more in depth; https://stackoverflow.com/a/35372152/7098259

Comment: @PatrickParker, ah, that latest link helped a lot.  Thank you.  Also, are there any other `Collections` that might have this concern as well?

Comment: @P.K. - Yes, Hashtable is another example (and its abstract version, Dictionary). Use HashMap instead.

Comment: @PatrickParker, thanks I'll be careful when using the two - a Stack and a Hashtable.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java generics were added after initial implementations of collections; [`Stack`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) is from Java 1.0 - and rather then break existing code when they added generics, it was decided to add classes that duplicate functionality (but provide a consistent API). That is why you should prefer a [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) - it provides an API consistent with all of the other Java `Collection`s.

Comment: wrong, `Stack<E>` also supports Java Generics.

Comment: So, just to be clear, you mean implementing a `Deque` interface instead of `Stack<>`?

Comment: @PatrickParker My wording is perhaps awkward. Collections weren't added until Java (1.)2, Generics are Java 5, and Deque was added in Java 6. But `Stack` predates all of that!

Comment: Generics have nothing to do with the reason, as Stack supports generics. The reason has more to do with the fact that Stack, like Vector, is inherently flawed due to how its synchronization works. They couldn't fix that as classes explicitly depending on that synchronization logic would then break.

Comment: It is correct that generics was added later.  It is not correct that they were the reason the collections hierarchy was created in addition to what Java already had.

Answer (score 6):

`Stack` extends `Vector` which means that it `synchronizes` for each individual operation.

Odds are you'll have one thread accessing the data structure, so synchronizing on each operation is a waste of CPU time.  You'll spend all of your time grabbing and releasing the lock on the object, and very little of it actually adding or removing items.